# angularjs ng-repeat one long unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

So in my current angular app my json structure looks like this:

```
0: Object
      $$hashKey: "004"
      Date: "2014-04-17"
      Items: Array[3]
1: Object
      $$hashKey: "005"
      Date: "2014-04-18"
      Items: Array[3]
2: Object
      $$hashKey: "006"
      Date: "2014-04-19"
      Items: Array[3]
```

I am trying to figure out how I can use ng-repeat to be able to obtain the below UL structure:

```
<ul>
<li class="date"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="date"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="date"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
</ul>
```

This is current my html setup:

```
<ul ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <li class="date" ng-repeat="day in Days">
    <strong>>{{ day.Date }}</strong>
  </li>

  <li class="item" ng-repeat="item in day.Items">
    <strong>>{{ item.Name }}</strong>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am wondering if its at all possible to achieve that ul structure I am looking for with my current json nested structure and if so how would I be able to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a bin http://jsbin.com/puvafefe/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='App'>
  <head>
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="tmpl">
          <li></li>
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="sCtr">
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat-start="obj in json">{{obj.date}}</li>
    <li ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="item in obj.items">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Js

```
var app = angular.module("App", []);

app.controller("sCtr", function($scope) {
  $scope.json = [
    {date: "2014-04-17", items: [1,2,3]},
    {date: "2014-04-18", items: [4,5,6]}
  ];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for example.

```
<ul ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <li class="date" ng-repeat-start="day in Days">
    <strong>>{{ day.Date }}</strong>
  </li>

  <li class="item" ng-repeat="item in day.Items">
    <strong>>{{ item.Name }}</strong>
  </li>
  <span ng-repeat-end></span>
</ul>
```

Or you can use anything else non visible, or you can make it invisible using css.